# Batch File to replace a specific value that it's always on the same position on a txt file

Tags: csv, batch-file, replace, cmd

I have set of files that differs between each others on content and number of rows. However, I want to increment always by 1 the 8th value of the first file line even if the files are different. The values are delimited by semi-colon and could be just a numeric value or a alpha-numeric (i.e. 123 or TBA1).

I've tried to use tokens and loops, but without success. I've just get to actually insert the value and after it the "+1" increment that I was trying to do. My attemps so far is right below

```
@Echo Off
Set "SrcFile=tf.fic"
Set "OutFile=ntf.text"
If Not Exist "%SrcFile%" Exit /B
(   For /F "UseBackQ EOL=, Tokens=1-8* Delims=;" %%A In ("%SrcFile%"
    ) Do For /F "Tokens=1-2* Delims=" %%I In ("%%H"
    ) Do Echo=%%A;%%B;%%C;%%D;%%E;%%F;%%G;%%I%%J+1;%%K)>"%OutFile%"
```

So, taking as an example a file like looks like this:

```
1;12;A;23;;23;ASD;TTA2;233;HD2;233
1;232;A;b;;A
```

The output file should have the following content:

```
1;12;A;23;;23;ASD;TTA3;233;HD2;233
1;232;A;b;;A
```

Note: some fields may be as empty (i.e. first line 5th field) and should be empty as well on the output file.

Comment: As your source file contains empty fields `;;` without taking precautions batch isn't suited well for your task as `for /f` takes successive delimiters as only one. PowerShell may fit better.

Comment: The inner `for /F` loop makes no sence since you did not specify any `delims`, so you will never get more than one `tokens`. Then there is the problem with empty fields. And you need to specify how the eighth field is built; is the prefix `TTA` always the same or always 3 characters long? The more precise you are the less we have to guess, so the more suitable will be the answers you will get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some advanced techniques:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\09\12\SO_57905573.cmd
@Echo Off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "SrcFile=tf.fic"
Set "OutFile=ntf.text"
If Not Exist "%SrcFile%" Exit /B

Set /P "FirstLine=" <"%SrcFile%"
Rem create (pseudo)array from FirstLine using self modifying code
Set i=1
Set "FirstLineCol[!i!]=%FirstLine:;="&Set /a i+=1&Set "FirstLineCol[!i!]=%"
rem Set FirstLine

rem strip possible letters from Col[8] and retain number
for /f "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" %%N in ("%FirstLineCol[8]%") Do Set /a "Num=%%N,Num1=%%N+1"
set "FirstLineCol[8]=!FirstLineCol[8]:%Num%=%Num1%!"

>"%OutFile%" (
  set /p "x=!FirstLineCol[1]!"<NUL
  for /l %%L in (2,1,%i%) Do set /p "x=;!FirstLineCol[%%L]!"<NUL
  echo(
  more +1 "%srcFile%"
)

type "%SrcFile%"
echo:
echo:
type "%OutFile%"
```

to yield this:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\09\12\SO_57905573.cmd
1;12;A;23;;23;ASD;TTA2;233;HD2;233
1;232;A;b;;A

1;12;A;23;;23;ASD;TTA3;233;HD2;233
1;232;A;b;;A
```

Answer (score 1):

I've taken @LotPings comment ("*batch isn't suited well for your task as for /f takes successive delimiters as only one*") as a challenge and have come up with the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "SrcFile=tf.fic"
Set "OutFile=ntf.text"
If Not Exist "%SrcFile%" Exit /B
If     Exist "%OutFile%" del "%OutFile%"

set FIRST=Y
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=#" %%x in ( "%SrcFile%" ) do (
    set "LINE=%%x"
    if defined FIRST (
        set "HASH=!LINE:;=;#!"
        for /f "usebackq tokens=1-8,* delims=#" %%a in ( '!HASH!' ) do (
            set ALPHA=
            set NUM=
            for /f "tokens=1 delims=0123456789"                 %%y in ( "%%h" ) do set ALPHA=%%y
            for /f "tokens=1 delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" %%y in ( "%%h" ) do set NUM=%%y
            set /a NUM=NUM+1
            set "LINE=%%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g!ALPHA!!NUM!;%%i"
            set "LINE=!LINE:#=!"
        )
        set FIRST=
    )
    >>"%OutFile%" echo !LINE!
)
echo ============================ Src
type "%SrcFile%"
echo ============================ Out
type "%OutFile%"
echo ============================
```

This works both when the eighth field is numeric:

```
============================ Src
1;12;A;23;;23;ASD;99;233
1;232;A;b;;A
============================ Out
1;12;A;23;;23;ASD;100;233
1;232;A;b;;A
============================
```

and when it is alphanumeric:

```
============================ Src
1;12;A;23;;23;ASD;TTA2;233
1;232;A;b;;A
============================ Out
1;12;A;23;;23;ASD;TTA3;233
1;232;A;b;;A
============================
```

**Notes / Explanation**

- The main loop operates over all lines of the file, buffering each line in `LINE`. Special processing happens only for the first line (when `FIRST` is defined).
- `HASH` is created from the first line by replacing all semicolons (`;`) with (`;#`), turning, for example, `aaa;;bbb` into `aaa;#;#bbb`.
- **NOTE**: The choice of `#` is more-or-less arbitrary, *so long as it will never appear in a real file*.
- The modified line can now be safely split into the first eight fields (`%%a` through `%%h`) and "all the rest" (`%%i`) as there will always be *something* between the delimiters, even for empty fields.
- We now break the eighth field (`%%h`) into its (optional) alpha part (`ALPHA`) and its numeric part (`NUM`). Somewhat perversely, this *relies* on the fact that adjacent delimiters are "rolled-in to one": the alpha part is delimited by *one or more* digits; the numeric part is delimited by one or more letters.
- **NOTE**: I am assuming that the eighth field is *always* an optional run of non-digits (e.g. `TTA`) followed by one or more digits (e.g. `2`). If this is *not* always the case (e.g. if there can be letters *after* the digit(s)), then adjustments would need to be made.
- **NOTE**: The current file only works for upper-case letters preceding the number. If lower-case letters, or other characters can be present, you would need to add these to the `delims=ABC...` clause.
- Having split the eighth field into its constituent parts, we increment the numeric part (using `SET /A`).
- We now reassemble the line. Because we split the line using `#`, the original `;` delimiters are still present, so don't need adding. The only exception is the eighth field, which due to it being further split into two parts will have lost its semicolon.
- Finally, we need to remove any left-over `#` characters we added. There won't be any in the first eight fields, but `%%i` (the "and all the rest" variable) may contain some.
- **NOTE**: If there are *only* eight fields on the first line, the current script will add a trailing semicolon that wasn't there before. If this matters, it is left as an exercise for the reader. (Probably involving the conditional appending of `;%%i`).

Answer (score 1):

Just for comparison,
at the cost of readability this PowerShell script could be condensed further:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\09\12\SO_57905573.ps1
$SrcFile = ".\tf.fic"
$OutFile = ".\ntf.text"

$Content = (Get-Content $SrcFile)
$Firstline = $Content[0] -split ';'
if($Firstline[7] -match '(\d+)$'){
  $Firstline[7]=$Firstline[7] -replace $Matches[1],(([int]$Matches[1])+1)
}
$Content[0] = $FirstLine -join ';'
$Content | Set-Content $OutFile
```

The index in PowerShell is zero based.